# ::GetClipboardData of CF_HDROP returns DROPFILE not STGMEDIUM?

Tags: winapi, clipboard

Docs for CF_HDROP says:

> The data consists of an STGMEDIUM structure that contains a global
>   memory object. The structure's hGlobal member points to a DROPFILES
>   structure as its hGlobal member.

but in fact when you use `GetClipboardData()` it returns data to the `DROPFILES` itself.  That is you don't get the data as a `STGMEDIUM` that you then have to access via the `hGlobal` member.  Why is that?  Docs wrong?  Missing docs/details of automatic conversion? or am I reading something wrong?

```
 typedef struct tagSTGMEDIUM {
     DWORD         tymed;   
     union {
     HBITMAP       hBitmap;
     HMETAFILEPICT hMetaFilePict;
     HENHMETAFILE  hEnhMetaFile;
     HGLOBAL       hGlobal;
     LPOLESTR      lpszFileName;
     IStream       *pstm;
     IStorage      *pstg;   
     } DUMMYUNIONNAME;   
     IUnknown *pUnkForRelease; 
 } uSTGMEDIUM;
```

Comment: The docs are targeted at the `OleGetClipboard()` API which is lower-level (gives you an `IDataObject` which you then query). `GetClipboardData()` is a higher level wrapper.

Comment: The [standard clipboard formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) documentation applies here. For `CF_HDROP` the API returns *"a handle to type `HDROP` that identifies a list of files. An application can retrieve information about the files by passing the handle to the [DragQueryFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragqueryfilew) function"*.